# How to get the value of a selected check from a fieldset in php?

Tags: php, html

I'm working a Pizza ordering form for a semester project, After finishing with my forms I'd to send the selected order from the user to an email, how do I get the value of the checkboxes and radio buttons?

This is my HTML how do I get the values the user selects when ordering pizza using php, so that I can later validate and send these values to a mail..

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Sizes</legend>
    <div class="orderrow">
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="sizes" id="size--small" value="small">
            <label class="form-check-label btn btn-danger" for="size--small">Small</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="sizes" id="size--regular" value="regular">
            <label class="form-check-label btn btn-danger" for="size--regular">Regular</label>
        </div><div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="sizes" id="size--large" value="large">
            <label class="form-check-label btn btn-danger" for="size--large">Large</label>
        </div><div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="sizes" id="size--exlarge" value="exlarge">
            <label class="form-check-label btn btn-danger" for="size--large">Extra-Large</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset><br>
</div>
```

Comment: There are mega tons of examples and tutorials out there...come back with code and specific issues/errors

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of examples out there, that's for sure, but it does depend on how you want to handle what happens when the user presses submit.

Do you want the information to go to a new page, or do you want the used to stay on the same page with perhaps a modal message saying that the order is successful?

If you want the former option:

- Wrap the HTML fields within a form and have the action pointing to the next web page.
- On the new web page, server side code, looking at either the POST or GET variables (could use REQUEST), decide what to do with them.
- Construct the new HTML displaying the contents of the form in which ever way you want.

If it's the latter option:

- No need to wrap the fields within a form, but the button which 'submits' the form, should have an onClick event to a JS function.
- The JS function will collate the values from the fields and using Ajax call a server side PHP file, passing through as either GET or POST variables, the values of the form.
- PHP server side code, will manipulate the values in whichever way required and return information to the client to be displayed, such as "OK" message.

The OP is too broad and vague to come up with a more definitive answer than this.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You solution seems to be advanced, I'm doing this for a school project but I'm willing to learn kindly suggest materials or some references I can read and get your suggested solutions. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if you put your fieldset into a form with the method get and add this PHP-script it should work. The variable `$s` is the size you defined by `value=""`

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
    $s = $_GET['sizes'];
    echo $s;

}

?>
```

Comment: for ordering stuff, always use method="post" for security. Sorry, my fault.